# PHP like serialized string in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a legacy PHP application which is using PHP's `serialize()` method to serialize the class and store it to a file and there are other applications using this string using `unserialize()` method to create object of the serialized class and use the data associated. I need to achieve similar serialization technique in .NET so that the output is same as PHP. I am thinking to use Reflection for this but still need to identify how I will make use of that. I have also tried the .NET serialization but the output is totally different.

Is there any other way I can do this?

consider example below -

**sample php class**

```
class SerializeTest
{
    var $test = 0;
    var $test1 = "testing";
    var $test2 = 1;
    var $test3 = "testing1";

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo serialize($this);
    }
}
```

**serialized string**

`O:13:"SerializeTest":4:{s:4:"test";i:0;s:5:"test1";s:7:"testing";s:5:"test2";i:1;s:5:"test3";s:8:"testing1";}`

**sample .NET Class**

```
class SerializeDemo
{
    internal int test = 0;
    internal string test1 = "testing";
    internal int test2 = 1;
    internal string test3 = "testing3";
}
```

**required serialized string**

`O:13:"SerializeTest":4:{s:4:"test";i:0;s:5:"test1";s:7:"testing";s:5:"test2";i:1;s:5:"test3";s:8:"testing1";}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Sharp Serialization Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial/)

> Sharp Serialization Library serializes and deserializes primitives,
>   ArrayLists and Hashtables, **compatible with PHP serialize()**. Use it for
>   SOAP/Web Services communications where Hashtables cannot be passed
>   otherwise, or saving to a file readable by php.